# MySQL-select query is very slow when there are a few results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing, query-optimization

I have `table1` with 1M rows in my db.

```
columns: {id, name, timestamp, tag, r, g, b}
indexes: {primary: id, index: timestamp, index: (tag,r,g,b)}
```

each rows has a tag (which is an integer) and a color, which is saved by its components (r,g,b) in seperate columns. my queries are supposed to be like:

```
SELECT * from table1 WHERE tag=... AND (r>... AND r<... AND g>... AND g<... AND b>... AND b<...) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 24;
```

the problem is that when there are only a few records in the db for the selected filters (tag and color), the query is very slow (15 seconds). it is also notable that when I remove `ORDER BY timestamp DESC` from the query, it runs very fast, even if there are a few results. how to solve the issue and make the query fast?

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "few", but 15 seconds seems like a long time.

You want an index on this query, on `(tag, r, g, b)`.

That said, this is not an optimal index; or more precisely, it is about as optimal as you can get in MySQL.  The real type of index that you want is an RD-Tree, which is optimized for ranges on different dimensions.  The primary use-case is GIS (geographic information systems).

However, I don't think that MySQL supports RD-Trees as a generic index type.  Hopefully, `tag` is highly selective and the above index will work well.

Comment: as I have mentioned in the question, I'm currently using an index on `(tag, r, g, b)`, but when there are less than 1000 results for example, it takes so long.

Comment: I couldn't get what you mean by `Hopefully, tag is highly selective and the above index will work well.`, could you please explain?

Comment: @Soheil . . . That a single tag matches few records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(tag, timestamp)
```

may help somewhat.

The general problem is that the Optimizer sees two semi-useful indexes but with no inadequate clues as to which one to pick.  And then it picks the less beneficial one.

Adding these may help when you have a relatively narrow choice for g or b:

```
INDEX(tag, g)
INDEX(tag, b)
```

Unfortunately you have 4 "ranges" in the the `WHERE` clause (timestamp, r, g, b) and the Optimizer can use only one.  I stuck `tag` in front of each (including your extant `(tag, r, g, b)`, which won't get beyond `r`).

`=` tests should go first; the index can end with one range; any subsequent range test (g,b, in your case) will be ignored in the index.

Comment: many thanks for your explanation. I tried (tag, timestamp) index but did not help noticeably. at the end I'm convinced I have to redefine some of my search logics and replace range queries with `=` queries.